# How do you change the viewport size of the sublimetext in Python?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to create my first plugin for Sublime Text 3.

How do I set the viewport size? I usually divide the layout into two, what I want to do is change the viewport size for the focused layout, so that I can read more content in the focused layout.

I was able to get the size of the viewport with the `viewport_extent()` method of the `view`, but I don't know how to set it to a new size.

Comment: what do you want to achieve by setting the viewport size? plugins do not have the ability to resize ST windows or panels, but you might be able to size the layout split when more than one row or column group is displayed - take a look at the command when you execute `View -> Layout -> Columns: 2` from the menu, for example.

Comment: yes,I usually divide the layout into two,what I want to do is change the viewport size for the focused layout,so that I can read more content in the focused layout

Comment: as you can't set viewport size directly, you will want to use `window.get_layout()` to get the current layout together with `window.set_layout` to set the new layout, passing in the necessary arguments to give the active group a larger size ratio.

Comment: it works!thanks very much.but how do you know the window class has a method named set_layout? I can't find it in official API document.

Comment: some things you have to explore manually unfortunately. In the ST console, you can use `dir(window)` to see all the available methods and properties on the `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins do not have the ability to resize ST panels, or directly resize a viewport, but you can size the layout split when more than one row or column group is displayed.

You will want to use `window.get_layout()` to get the current layout together with `window.set_layout` to set the new layout, passing in the necessary arguments to give the active/focused group a larger size ratio.

A single pane layout looks like this in `get_layout`:

```
{'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1]], 'rows': [0.0, 1.0], 'cols': [0.0, 1.0]}
```

An evenly split 2 column layout looks like this:

```
{'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]], 'rows': [0.0, 1.0], 'cols': [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]}
```

A wider left column might look like this:

```
{'cells': [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]], 'rows': [0.0, 1.0], 'cols': [0.0, 0.75, 1.0]}
```

you can determine which group is active using `window.active_group()`, and decide how to set the ratio based on that.

---

Note: some API functions don't appear in the official documentation. For exploration purposes, it can be useful to execute `dir(window)` or `dir(view)` in the ST console, to see what properties and methods are available.

Comment: I use the method that you said has already realized the function I want.I really appreciate that you have taught me so much.